# Apache POI, table positioning is being ignored (.docx, xwpf)

Tags: java, apache-poi, xwpf

I am trying to position a table using the tblPr element, and its attributes tblpX and tblpY. My issue is that when I open the .docx file the table is in the top-left of the page, ignoring the tblpX and tblPY values. You can find a details of how the .docx tables get positioned [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/documentformat.openxml.wordprocessing.tablepositionproperties(v=office.14).aspx) or [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff534469(v=office.12).aspx). It should look something like:

```
<w:tbl>
  <w:tblPr>
  <w:tblpPr w:vertAnchor="text" w:tblpY="200" />
  </w:tblPr>  
  …
</w:tbl>
```

Apache POI does not offer a "tblpY" and "tblpX" attribute, so the only way I can think to add this attribute is manually. Here my code to do so:

```
public static XWPFTable createTable(XWPFDocument doc) {

  //CTTbl ctTable = CTTbl.Factory.newInstance();
  XWPFTable table = doc.createTable();//new XWPFTable(ctTable, doc, 0, 0);

  XmlObject x = (XmlObject) table.getCTTbl().getTblPr();
  XmlCursor c = x.newCursor();  // Create a cursor at the element
  c.toNextToken();              // Move cursor after the tblPr tag
  c.insertElement("tblPr", "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main");

  c.toPrevSibling(); //Now go to the tblPr
  XmlObject x2 = c.getObject(); //Get the tblPr object
  c.dispose();
  c = x2.newCursor(); //Now our cursor is inside the second tblPr
  c.toNextToken();
  c.insertAttributeWithValue("tblpX", "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main", "500");
  c.insertAttributeWithValue("tblpY", "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main", "500");
  c.dispose();

  XWPFTableRow tr = table.getRow(0);
  XWPFTableCell cell = tr.getCell(0);
  cell.setText("some text");

  return table;  

}
```

I opened the .docx and verified that the following is inside of the document.xml

```
<w:tbl>
  <w:tblPr>
    <w:tblPr w:tblpX="500" w:tblpY="500"/>
    <w:tblW w:w="0" w:type="auto"/>
    <w:tblBorders>
      <w:top w:val="single"/>
      <w:left w:val="single"/>
      <w:bottom w:val="single"/>
      <w:right w:val="single"/>
      <w:insideH w:val="single"/>
      <w:insideV w:val="single"/>
    </w:tblBorders>
  </w:tblPr>
  <w:tr>
    <w:tc>
      <w:p>
        <w:r>
          <w:t>some text</w:t>
        </w:r>
      </w:p>
    </w:tc>
  </w:tr>
</w:tbl>
```

So what am I doing wrong? Why is the table still in the top left? Why is microsoft word ignoring my tblpX and tblpY values?

Comment: Oh!!! I found the solution!

Answer (score 2):

The child node inside tblPr is supposed to be:
tblpPr NOT tblPr!

that single difference in syntax of a "p" was throwing me off.

Anyway, Hopefully someone can learn from this. E.g. there was no StackOverflow solution on how to use Apache POI to position a table absolutely... until now mwahahaha